How much of a MOSFET can you strip before it no longer functions?
I'm writing a program / game for fun to simulate N-type and P-type doped semiconductors. The goal is not to be accurate but fun, but accuracy would be nice.
While developing, I was wondering how much of a MOSFET can be removed until it no longer works.
Below I've attached a picture of a traditional pMOSFET (omitting pinch off effects entirely). From left-to-right, I continue to remove parts of the "MOSFET" device until it's basically a NP diode with a metal oxide layer.

Can the right-most diagram exist as a switch? Where a diode may be controlled in the reverse bias condition by applying a voltage to the gate or not?
If not, at which point in the diagram will the device malfunction?
